# promise and function callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to know what the difference between promises and a traditional callback is. If they are the same then why do we use promises or if they are not same which is the best approach

using callback functionality

```
$.get('userDetails', {'name': 'joe'}, function(data) {
    $('#userAge').text(data.age);
});
```

using promises functionality

```
$http.get('userDetails', {'name': 'joe'})
    .then(function(response) {
        $('#userAge').text(response.age);
    });
```

Comment: Promises are significantly more versatile  because they can be chained and any rejections get passed down the chain. Any error in a callback never gets caught anywhere. Really doesn't seem like you did much research on this before asking

Comment: [how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Promises are not callbacks ... the functions passed to `.then/.catch` are called back when the promise resolves, so yes, they are callbacks, but Promises themselves are not callbacks